Project Collaboration Challenges
To all the non-UI and UX designers here.
I'm particularly interested in the organizational aspects of projects beyond the design process itself, such as collaboration, setting up folder structures, approval workflows, naming conventions, and managing asset hand-offs. What have been your biggest pain points?
Can you describe your biggest challenges when collaborating with your team on projects? Specifically, how do you find your current workflow for managing and storing design assets impacts your day to day work?
Are your current tools effective in facilitating seamless collaboration, or do you find yourself switching between them frequently? We know Figma handles collaboration really well and for those using Figma for graphic design, the questions above still apply.

This is potentially a good question, but because of the format of the forum, the questions need to be a bit more specific.

Managing people and seamlessly imposing a specific workflow is a challenge in itself.
